# Rails 3 routing - bypass :user when no user exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I don't think this is possible, but figured I'd ask just in case.

I have a route file like:

```
root :to => 'info#home'
match '/about' => 'info#about'
match ':user' => 'users#profile'
match '*a', :to => 'application#not_found'
```

If I go to `site.com/nonsense` (assuming "nonsense" isn't a registered user) I expect an error, but would like the error to be treated as an unknown page rather than an unknown user.

That is, my log file shows

```
{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"profile", "user" => "nonsense"}
```

but I want it to show

```
{"controller"=>"application", "action"=>"not_found", "a"=>"nonsense"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your current routes dont leave a differentiation between `match '*a'` and `match ':user'` as the same regex applies to both and will always land in the `users#profile` action being hit

If you want to do this in the router and not in a controller conditional, look into Routing Constraints - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: I will leave it as an "answer" so you can accept it in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in the router and not in a controller conditional, look into Routing Constraints - guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def profile
  user = User.where(id: params[:id]).first

  unless user
    redirect_to not_found_path(a: params[:id])

    # or

    render partial: 'application/not_found'

    # or something along these lines
  end
end
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm currently doing. I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but this functions just fine.